# HID FileStream not working on Windows 7

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-7, hid

In my development machine, I used Windows 10 to create a WPF that receives and sends buffer to my HID Device (custom game controller).

It works great on any Windows 10 that I try, but some of my clients runs Windows 7 (can't upgrade) and I couldn't get it to work.

The write method throw the exception:

> The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation.

```
    public static bool SendBufferToDevice(HIDDev device, byte[] buffer)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (device)
            {
                device.fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
                return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The read method throw the same exception:

> The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation.

```
    public static byte[] ReceiveBufferFromDevice(HIDDev device, int bufferSize)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read = device.fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return buffer;
        }
    }
```

I've tried to change the size and the type of the buffer that I sent to method, but no success. Also, as said before, this exact code is working on Windows 10.

Part of the HIDDev class:

```
public class HIDDev : IDisposable
    {

        // device handle
        private IntPtr handle;
        // safe file handle
        SafeFileHandle shandle;
        // stream
        private FileStream _fileStream;
        public FileStream fileStream 
        {
          get { return _fileStream; }
          /* do not expose this setter */
          internal set { _fileStream = value; }
        }


...

  }
```

Is there anything that I need to do that only apply to < w10 versions?

**EDITED:**

As asked, the HID classes:

> Native.cs

```
using System;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;


namespace HIDRealdrive
{
    class Native
    {
        /* invalid handle value */
        public static IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);


        #region kernel32.dll


        /* read access */
        public const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
        /* write access */
        public const uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
        /* Enables subsequent open operations on a file or device to request 
         * write access.*/
        public const uint FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x2;
        /* Enables subsequent open operations on a file or device to request
         * read access. */
        public const uint FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x1;
        /* The file or device is being opened or created for asynchronous I/O. */
        public const uint FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED = 0x40000000;
        /* Opens a file or device, only if it exists. */
        public const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
        /* Opens a file, always. */
        public const uint OPEN_ALWAYS = 4;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        /* opens files that access usb hid devices */
        public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string strName, 
            uint nAccess, uint nShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurity, 
            uint nCreationFlags, uint nAttributes, IntPtr lpTemplate);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        /* closes file */
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static public extern int WriteFile(IntPtr hFile, ref byte lpBuffer, int nNumberOfBytesToWrite);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static public extern bool ReadFile(IntPtr hFile, ref byte lpBuffer, int nNumberOfBytesToRead);

        #endregion
        #region hid.dll


        /* The HIDD_ATTRIBUTES structure contains vendor information about a 
         * HIDClass device.*/
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct HiddAttributtes
        {
            /* size in bytes */
            public Int32 Size;
            /* vendor id */
            public Int16 VendorID;
            /* product id */
            public Int16 ProductID;
            /* hid vesion number */
            public Int16 VersionNumber;
        }

        //Capacidades totais do Dispositivo
        public struct HIDP_CAPS
        {
            public Int16 Usage;
            public Int16 UsagePage;
            public Int16 InputReportByteLength;
            public Int16 OutputReportByteLength;
            public Int16 FeatureReportByteLength;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 17)]
            public Int16[] Reserved;
            public Int16 NumberLinkCollectionNodes;
            public Int16 NumberInputButtonCaps;
            public Int16 NumberInputValueCaps;
            public Int16 NumberInputDataIndices;
            public Int16 NumberOutputButtonCaps;
            public Int16 NumberOutputValueCaps;
            public Int16 NumberOutputDataIndices;
            public Int16 NumberFeatureButtonCaps;
            public Int16 NumberFeatureValueCaps;
            public Int16 NumberFeatureDataIndices;
        }



        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        /* gets HID class Guid */
        public static extern void HidD_GetHidGuid(out Guid gHid);

        /* gets hid device attributes */
        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean HidD_GetAttributes(IntPtr hFile,
            ref HiddAttributtes attributes);

        /* gets usb manufacturer string */
        [DllImport("hid.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean HidD_GetManufacturerString(IntPtr hFile,
            StringBuilder buffer, Int32 bufferLength);

        /* gets product string */
        [DllImport("hid.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean HidD_GetProductString(IntPtr hFile,
            StringBuilder buffer, Int32 bufferLength);

        /* gets serial number string */
        [DllImport("hid.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool HidD_GetSerialNumberString(IntPtr hDevice,
            StringBuilder buffer, Int32 bufferLength);

        //Novos Imports do GenericHid_62
        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern Boolean HidD_FlushQueue(SafeFileHandle HidDeviceObject);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern Boolean HidD_FreePreparsedData(IntPtr PreparsedData);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern Boolean HidD_GetFeature(SafeFileHandle HidDeviceObject, Byte[] lpReportBuffer,
                                                       Int32 ReportBufferLength);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern Boolean HidD_GetInputReport(SafeFileHandle HidDeviceObject, Byte[] lpReportBuffer,
                                                           Int32 ReportBufferLength);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern Boolean HidD_GetNumInputBuffers(SafeFileHandle HidDeviceObject, ref Int32 NumberBuffers);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern Boolean HidD_GetPreparsedData(SafeFileHandle HidDeviceObject, ref IntPtr PreparsedData);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern Boolean HidD_SetFeature(SafeFileHandle HidDeviceObject, Byte[] lpReportBuffer,
                                                       Int32 ReportBufferLength);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern Boolean HidD_SetNumInputBuffers(SafeFileHandle HidDeviceObject, Int32 NumberBuffers);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern Boolean HidD_SetOutputReport(SafeFileHandle HidDeviceObject, Byte[] lpReportBuffer,
                                                            Int32 ReportBufferLength);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern Int32 HidP_GetCaps(IntPtr PreparsedData, ref HIDP_CAPS Capabilities);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern Int32 HidP_GetValueCaps(Int32 ReportType, Byte[] ValueCaps, ref Int32 ValueCapsLength,
                                                       IntPtr PreparsedData);


        #endregion
        #region setupapi.dll


        /* Return only devices that are currently present in a system. */
        public const int DIGCF_PRESENT = 0x02;
        /* Return devices that support device interfaces for the specified 
         * device interface classes. */
        public const int DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0x10;

        /* structure returned by SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces */
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct DeviceInterfaceData
        {
            /* size of fixed part of structure */
            public int Size;
            /* The GUID for the class to which the device interface belongs. */
            public Guid InterfaceClassGuid;
            /* Can be one or more of the following: SPINT_ACTIVE, 
             * SPINT_DEFAULT, SPINT_REMOVED */
            public int Flags;
            /* do not use */
            public IntPtr Reserved;
        }

        /* A structure contains the path for a device interface.*/
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct DeviceInterfaceDetailData
        {
            /* size of fixed part of structure */
            public int Size;
            /* device path, as to be used by CreateFile */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 512)]
            public string DevicePath;
        }

        /* function returns a handle to a device information set that contains
         * requested device information elements for a local computer */
        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref Guid gClass, 
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string strEnumerator, 
            IntPtr hParent, uint nFlags);

        /* The function enumerates the device interfaces that are contained in 
         * a device information set.*/
        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(
            IntPtr lpDeviceInfoSet, uint nDeviceInfoData, ref Guid gClass,
            uint nIndex, ref DeviceInterfaceData oInterfaceData);

        /* The SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail function returns details about 
         * a device interface.*/
        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
            IntPtr lpDeviceInfoSet, ref DeviceInterfaceData oInterfaceData,
            ref DeviceInterfaceDetailData oDetailData, 
            uint nDeviceInterfaceDetailDataSize, ref uint nRequiredSize,
            IntPtr lpDeviceInfoData);

        /* destroys device list */
        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(IntPtr lpInfoSet);


        #endregion

    }
}
```

> HIDInfo.cs

```
namespace HIDRealdrive
{
    public class HIDInfo
    {
        /* device path */
        public string Path { get; private set; }
        /* vendor ID */
        public short Vid { get; private set; }
        /* product id */
        public short Pid { get; private set; }
        /* usb product string */
        public string Product { get; private set; }
        /* usb manufacturer string */
        public string Manufacturer { get; private set; }
        /* usb serial number string */
        public string SerialNumber { get; private set; }

        /* constructor */
        public HIDInfo(string product, string serial, string manufacturer, 
            string path, short vid, short pid)
        {
            /* copy information */
            Product = product;
            SerialNumber = serial;
            Manufacturer = manufacturer;
            Path = path;
            Vid = vid;
            Pid = pid;
        }
    }
}
```

> HIDDev.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace HIDRealdrive
{
    public class HIDDev : IDisposable
    {

        /* device handle */
        private IntPtr handle;
        /* safe file handle */
        SafeFileHandle shandle;
        /* stream */
        private FileStream _fileStream;
        //conectado
        private bool isConnected = false;

        internal Native.HIDP_CAPS Capabilities;
        private string[] capabilitiesStrings = new string[16];

        //Retorna a conexão
        public bool IsConnected { get { return isConnected; } }


        /* stream */
        public FileStream fileStream 
        {
            get { return _fileStream; }
            /* do not expose this setter */
            internal set { _fileStream = value; }
        }

        /* dispose */
        public void Dispose()
        {
            /* deal with file stream */
            if (_fileStream != null) {
                /* close stream */
                _fileStream.Close();
                /* get rid of object */
                _fileStream = null;
            }

            /* close handle */
            Native.CloseHandle(handle);
        }

        /* open hid device */
        public bool Open(HIDInfo dev)
        {


            /* opens hid device file */
            handle = Native.CreateFile(dev.Path, 
                Native.GENERIC_READ | Native.GENERIC_WRITE,
                Native.FILE_SHARE_READ | Native.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                IntPtr.Zero, Native.OPEN_EXISTING, Native.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                IntPtr.Zero);

            /* whops */
            if (handle == Native.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                isConnected = false;
                return false;
            }
            isConnected = true;

            /* build up safe file handle */
            shandle = new SafeFileHandle(handle, false);

            capabilitiesStrings = GetDeviceCapabilities(shandle);
            /* prepare stream - async */
            _fileStream = new FileStream(shandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
                32, true);

            /* report status */
            return true;
        }

        /*Recebe informações totais do Dispositivo*/

        string[] GetDeviceCapabilities(SafeFileHandle hidHandle)
        {
            var preparsedData = new IntPtr();
            string[] capabilitiesStrings = new string[16];

            try
            {
                //  ***
                //  API function: HidD_GetPreparsedData

                //  Purpose: retrieves a pointer to a buffer containing information about the device's capabilities.
                //  HidP_GetCaps and other API functions require a pointer to the buffer.

                //  Requires: 
                //  A handle returned by CreateFile.
                //  A pointer to a buffer.

                //  Returns:
                //  True on success, False on failure.
                //  ***

                Native.HidD_GetPreparsedData(hidHandle, ref preparsedData);

                //  ***
                //  API function: HidP_GetCaps

                //  Purpose: find out a device's capabilities.
                //  For standard devices such as joysticks, you can find out the specific
                //  capabilities of the device.
                //  For a custom device where the software knows what the device is capable of,
                //  this call may be unneeded.

                //  Accepts:
                //  A pointer returned by HidD_GetPreparsedData
                //  A pointer to a HIDP_CAPS structure.

                //  Returns: True on success, False on failure.
                //  ***

                Int32 result = Native.HidP_GetCaps(preparsedData, ref Capabilities);
                if ((result != 0))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("");
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Usage: " + Convert.ToString(Capabilities.Usage, 16));
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Usage Page: " + Convert.ToString(Capabilities.UsagePage, 16));
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Input Report Byte Length: " + Capabilities.InputReportByteLength);
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Output Report Byte Length: " + Capabilities.OutputReportByteLength);
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Feature Report Byte Length: " + Capabilities.FeatureReportByteLength);
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Number of Link Collection Nodes: " + Capabilities.NumberLinkCollectionNodes);
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Number of Input Button Caps: " + Capabilities.NumberInputButtonCaps);
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Number of Input Value Caps: " + Capabilities.NumberInputValueCaps);
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Number of Input Data Indices: " + Capabilities.NumberInputDataIndices);
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Number of Output Button Caps: " + Capabilities.NumberOutputButtonCaps);
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Number of Output Value Caps: " + Capabilities.NumberOutputValueCaps);
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Number of Output Data Indices: " + Capabilities.NumberOutputDataIndices);
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Number of Feature Button Caps: " + Capabilities.NumberFeatureButtonCaps);
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Number of Feature Value Caps: " + Capabilities.NumberFeatureValueCaps);
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Number of Feature Data Indices: " + Capabilities.NumberFeatureDataIndices);

                    capabilitiesStrings[0]=("Full Device Capabilities Report:");
                    capabilitiesStrings[1] = ("  Usage: " + Convert.ToString(Capabilities.Usage, 16));
                    capabilitiesStrings[2] = ("  Usage Page: " + Convert.ToString(Capabilities.UsagePage, 16));
                    capabilitiesStrings[3] = ("  Input Report Byte Length: " + Capabilities.InputReportByteLength);
                    capabilitiesStrings[4] = ("  Output Report Byte Length: " + Capabilities.OutputReportByteLength);
                    capabilitiesStrings[5] = ("  Feature Report Byte Length: " + Capabilities.FeatureReportByteLength);
                    capabilitiesStrings[6] = ("  Number of Link Collection Nodes: " + Capabilities.NumberLinkCollectionNodes);
                    capabilitiesStrings[7] = ("  Number of Input Button Caps: " + Capabilities.NumberInputButtonCaps);
                    capabilitiesStrings[8] = ("  Number of Input Value Caps: " + Capabilities.NumberInputValueCaps);
                    capabilitiesStrings[9] = ("  Number of Input Data Indices: " + Capabilities.NumberInputDataIndices);
                    capabilitiesStrings[10] = ("  Number of Output Button Caps: " + Capabilities.NumberOutputButtonCaps);
                    capabilitiesStrings[11] = ("  Number of Output Value Caps: " + Capabilities.NumberOutputValueCaps);
                    capabilitiesStrings[12] = ("  Number of Output Data Indices: " + Capabilities.NumberOutputDataIndices);
                    capabilitiesStrings[13] = ("  Number of Feature Button Caps: " + Capabilities.NumberFeatureButtonCaps);
                    capabilitiesStrings[14] = ("  Number of Feature Value Caps: " + Capabilities.NumberFeatureValueCaps);
                    capabilitiesStrings[15] = ("  Number of Feature Data Indices: " + Capabilities.NumberFeatureDataIndices);
                    //  ***
                    //  API function: HidP_GetValueCaps

                    //  Purpose: retrieves a buffer containing an array of HidP_ValueCaps structures.
                    //  Each structure defines the capabilities of one value.
                    //  This application doesn't use this data.

                    //  Accepts:
                    //  A report type enumerator from hidpi.h,
                    //  A pointer to a buffer for the returned array,
                    //  The NumberInputValueCaps member of the device's HidP_Caps structure,
                    //  A pointer to the PreparsedData structure returned by HidD_GetPreparsedData.

                    //  Returns: True on success, False on failure.
                    //  ***                    

                    Int32 vcSize = Capabilities.NumberInputValueCaps;
                    var valueCaps = new Byte[vcSize];

                    //Native.HidP_GetValueCaps(Native.HidP_Input, valueCaps, ref vcSize, preparsedData);

                    // (To use this data, copy the ValueCaps byte array into an array of structures.)              
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                //  ***
                //  API function: HidD_FreePreparsedData

                //  Purpose: frees the buffer reserved by HidD_GetPreparsedData.

                //  Accepts: A pointer to the PreparsedData structure returned by HidD_GetPreparsedData.

                //  Returns: True on success, False on failure.
                //  ***

                if (preparsedData != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Native.HidD_FreePreparsedData(preparsedData);
                }
            }
            return capabilitiesStrings;
        }

        /* close hid device */
        public void Close()
        {
            /* deal with file stream */
            if (_fileStream != null) {
                /* close stream */
                _fileStream.Close();
                /* get rid of object */
                _fileStream = null;
            }

            /* close handle */
            Native.CloseHandle(handle);
            isConnected = false;
        }

        /* write record */
        public void Write(byte[] data)
        {

            /* Cria task e write some bytes */ 
            fileStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            /* flush! */
            _fileStream.Flush();
        }

        public async Task WriteAsync(byte[] data)
        {
            /* Cria task e write some bytes */
            Task t =_fileStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
            await t;
            /* flush! */
            _fileStream.Flush();
        }

        /* read record */
        public void Read(byte[] data)
        {
            /* get number of bytes */
            int n = 0, bytes = data.Length;

            /* read buffer */
            while (n != bytes) {
                /* read data */
                int rc = _fileStream.Read(data, n, bytes - n);
                /* update pointers */
                n += rc;
            }
        }

        public byte[] GetInputReport(byte[] inBuffer, int buffLenght)
        {
            Native.HidD_GetInputReport(shandle, inBuffer, buffLenght);
            return inBuffer;

        }

        /*Mais info sobre a placa*/

        public string[] GetFullDeviceCapabilities(string[] cap)
        {
            return cap;

        }

        public string GetFullDeviceCapabilitiesString()
        {
            string capabilities = "";

            for (int i = 0; i <= capabilitiesStrings.Length-1; i++)
            {
                capabilities = capabilities + capabilitiesStrings[i];
            }

            return capabilities;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. `HIDDev` is missing a lot of critical details

Comment: Added more code, please let me know if you need anything else. Thanks!

Comment: did you try calling `Flush` on write?

Comment: Yes, added now and checked that the method Write is also throwing the same exception as the Read. The WriteAsync is not throwing exceptions. Question edited. Flush wont solved it because the exception on Read occurs before.

Answer (score 0):

Just stopped to try to reinvent the wheel and used the

> HidSharp

from  https://www.zer7.com/software/hidsharp

And it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Get the device capabilities, it will say the size of the input and output reports.

YOU MUST MAKE YOUR BUFFER MATCH THIS SIZE.

And honestly I quit trying to use file streams on Win 7 because they keep hanging in the kernel waiting for a semephore.

Use the HIDAPI and interop those calls. (not sure but think that may be what HidSharp has already done?)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/introduction-to-hid-concepts